# Two or more similar counts on fact table in dimensional modelling

Tags: sql, database-design, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I have designed a fact table that stores the  facts for a specific date dimension and an action type such as create, update or cancelled. The facts can be create and cancelled only once, but update many times.

```
myfact
---------------
date_key
location_key
action_type_key
```

This will allow me to get a count for all the updates done, all the new ones created for a period and specify a specific region through the location dimension.

Now in addition I also have 2 counts for each fact, i.e. Number of People, Number of Buildings. There is no relation between these. And I would like to query on how many of the facts having a specific count, such as how many have 10 building, how many have 9 etc.

What would be the best table design for these. Basically I see the following options, but am open to hear better solutions.

1. add the counts as reference info in the fact table as `people_count` and `building_count`
2. add a dimension for each of these that stores the valid options, i.e. `people dimension` that stores a `key` and a count and `building dimension` that stores a `key` and a count. The main fact will have a `people_key` and a `building_key`
3. add one dimension for the count these is used for both people and building counts, i.e. `count dimension` that stores a `key` and a generic count. The main fact will have a `people_count_key` and a `building_count_key`

Comment: "but update many times"  That's not a proper fact table.  That's some kind of summary table.  A proper fact table is insert-only.  Why aren't you simply using a proper fact table?  Why are you updating summary counts?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more -- fact tables are usually not updated (except in some special cases). What is that this is supposed to count? How do people relate to buildings?

Comment: The information interested in is the how many times a record was create, how many times are record was updated, etc. and then also combine this with the other dimension. People are not related to building, just interested in the grouping and frequences of occurences of each counts.

Comment: given the problem as stated, a dimensional modelling approach seems like massive overkill. Is this a simplification of the real problem? What sort of volumes of data are you expecting?

Comment: maybe around 3000 insert per month, 2000 updates. The number of additional dimensions is about 8 so I can group over location, date, user time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First your counts are essentially "dimensions" in the purest sense (you can think of dimensions as a way to group records for reporting purposes).  The question though is whether dimensional modeling is what you want to do.  I think you are better off as seeing this as something of an implicit dimension than you are to add dimension tables.  What this means essentially is that dimension tables add nothing and they create corner cases of errors I just don't think are very helpful unless you need to track a bunch of information related to numbers.

If it were me I would just add the counts to the fact table, not to other tables.